# R arrange function seems not to be working

Tags: r

I am having a dataframe with timestamps that also have decimal values. I want to calculate the difference between the first and all other events from the same group. To do that I use the following code:

```
values <- c("1671535501.862424", "1671535502.060679","1671535502.257422",
            "1671535502.472993", "1671535502.652619","1671535502.856569",
            "1671535503.048685", "1671535503.245988")
column_b <- c("a", "a","a","a","a","a","a","a")
values<-as.numeric(values)


#-- Calculate differences
data <- data.frame(values,column_b) #create data frame
res <- data %>% 
  group_by(column_b) %>% 
  arrange(values) %>% 
  mutate(time=values-lag(values, default = first(values)))
```

In general, the code does exactly what I expect it to do. It groups them, arranges them, and calculates the difference for each group. The output looks like this:

```
> res
# A tibble: 8 × 3
# Groups:   column_b [2]
       values column_b       time
        <dbl> <fct>         <dbl>
1 1671535502. a        0    
2 1671535502. a        0.198
3 1671535502. a        0.197
4 1671535502. a        0.216
5 1671535503. a        0.180
6 1671535503. a        0.204
7 1671535503. a        0.192
8 1671535503. a        0.197
```

Nevertheless, I have my doubts about the math results. If I am not mistaken, the values in this example are prearranged. But even if that was not the case, `arrange()` should have done the job. Hence, IF it is arranging the values, how can the 4th have a larger value than the 5th? There are multiple examples where we see that it does not make sense. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The 4th value of `values` equals `1671535502.47`, the 5th value `1671535502.65`, so the 4th < 5th. You aren't arraging by `time`.

Comment: based on your description (I want to calculate the difference between the first and all other events ) it must be `mutate(time=values - first(values))`

Comment: @RicVillalba I found the "formula" in another post. Just took it for granted as correct... thank you, your comment solved my problem!